# Transfer files client-server inside a SSH session

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to transfer files (client-server) from inside a ssh session?.

I know how to transfer files using SCP, This question is about transference from inside a ssh session. 
For example I start the ssh session:

```
ssh root@example.com
```

I perform some operations

```
echo "Test" > FILE
```

I transfer the files (pseudocode)

```
remotecp FILE client_directory
```

I want to know this because I want to make an automation script from some process (mostly backup operations) and I want to make it the most atomic way possible.

Comment: scp is the command to do that. If you set up a [ssh key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys), then you can automate it.

Comment: I guess it depends if you running your client with a external IP address or not. If so, `who mom hates` show your IP

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I know that method, I want to know if there is a way to do it without closing sessions like the example above.

Comment: @Serge Probably with some [kermit](http://www.kermitproject.org/) hack.

Comment: @jasonwryan: You are right, that question is what I needed. Sorry I did some research but I miss that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your client with a external IP address:

```
IP=$(who mom hates | awk '{print $5}' | tr -d ')' |tr -d '(')
scp FILE USER@${IP}:~/some/path
```

Comment: Thanks, but not external IP address.

Comment: Interactively you can suspend the connection with '~&' but I do not think this would work for scripts